# Problemas con Git al actualizar a Mojave

Tags: git, gitlab, macos

He actualizado a Mojave y ahora no puedo hacer un git pull, el debug me pinta lo siguiente.

```
oskar@drupal (master) $ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin master
18:25:47.483902 git.c:440               trace: built-in: git pull origin master
18:25:47.486580 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok origin master
18:25:47.491597 git.c:440               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok origin master
18:25:47.496738 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh git@gitlab.com 'git-upload-pack '\''group/campus-project-drupal.git'\'''
```

He buscado en google, y he encontrado que parece que existen problemas con Mojave, he seguido los pasos recomendados (xcode-select --reset) pero sigo con el mismo problema.

También he probado a borrar todo e instalarlo otra vez, pero no he conseguido nada.

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Oskar

Comment: Gracias @porloscerrosΨ, no me he dado cuenta que estaba en es.